# How to control height and width behavioral to be based on parent or child?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
new Center(
  child: new GestureDetector(
    child: new Center(
      child: new Text('Center'),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there a generic way to force GestureDetector to adopt the size of its parent (the outer Center) rather than the size of its child (the inner Center)?

Want to adjust heights according parent in gesturedetector!

Comment: Couldn't get the problem that you are trying to solve here.